# How do I run two processes and find out when one ends in bash

Tags: bash, shell, background-process

I was thinking to do something like this:

```
command1 & command2
wait
```

Will this work? I want to proceed when command2 finishes, but command1 can still be running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The semicolon `;` is the sequencing operator. So in

```
command1 & command2 ; command3
```

or equivalently

```
command1 &
command2
command3
```

`command3` will run after `command2` while `command1` may still be running.

The command `wait` will wait for all background processes (`command1` in your example) to complete.

Comment: Thank you! I was worried that a sequencing operator might wait for command1, as well, so if I understand correctly, the & operator runs it in the background of all following processes.

Comment: It is running asynchroneously in the background, yes.